# What plant is this? It is a new weed in my field!

Tags: weed-control

A suculent plant resistant to the herbicides?

[image]

Comment: In what part of the world do you live?

Comment: Appears to be a member of the Crassula family, looks a bit like a Kalanchoe - Kalanchoe hirta does have tuberous roots like this, not sure if it is that, though it is endemic in parts of Africa...

Comment: It is in the center of Romania and this plant is a new one in this area like weed. I recognized it like an ornamental plant - Kalanchoe?!  We are interested in control methods or solution...